# Double Spacing Footnotes but having it up against line

Tags: footnotes

I have looked around but I can't compute how to fix my problem.  My footnotes have to be single spaced in the footnote and double spaced between them.  They must also rest against the black line that marks the footnote area.  I can't determine how to have the double spacing between footnotes, but still be flush against the line.  Here is some code as to what I am doing

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
     \usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Commitment Variables}
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{10cm}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} \\
    \hline
    $commitmentcounter$\tablefootnote{Words used: pride, visit, leader, unity, campus, legacy, important, environment, only, home, comfort, mom, dad, mother, father, family} & The number of words in both essays used by people who did come to Baylor. \\
   $commitmentpercent$ & The percentage of words that are commitment words. \\
    $faithcounter$\tablefootnote{Words used: shall, unto, lord, thou, thy, ye, God, son, hath, Israel, king, people, house, before, children, against, shalt, land, day, hand, behold, saith, sons, hast, o, over, she, David, great, Jesus, thine, father, neither, give, take, am, forth, brought, name, away, pass, two, according, days, city, earth, Moses, thereof, whom, know} & The number of words in both essays used to express their faith. \\
    $faithpercent$ & The percentage of words that are faith words. \\
    $baylorcounter$\tablefootnote{Words Used: Baylor, bears, bear, Waco, oso, quadrangle, ivy, burleson, hankamer, Louise, Herrington, truett, dia del
} & The number of words in both essays used to signal their knowledge of Baylor. \\
    $baylorpercent$ & The percentage of words that are Baylor specific. \\
    $totalbible$ & The number of times in both essays that a book of the Bible was referenced. \\
    $biblepercent$ & The percentage of words that are books of the Bible. \\
    $admincounter$\tablefootnote{Words Used: top, choice, first, dream, dreamed, always, growing, grown, grow, wonderful, visit, blessed, experience, passion, passionate, tradition, atmosphere, values, perfect, heart} & The number of times in both essays in which words given my by the admissions team were used. \\
    $adminpercent$ & The percentage of words that are from the admissions team. \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```